# Passing an Ember Handlebars Helper Result to a Component

Tags: ember.js

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around Ember.js.

I'm trying to pass the value for *selected* to a component (*course-select*), but  *selected* has to be determined **first** using a value derived from the "#each" block (*competency.id*).

I've written a helper capable of correctly determining the value and can send it back to the template:

```
{{current-course-helper competency.id}}  // 32
```

What I need to do is pass the helper result to the component (*course-select*) as the value for *selected*.

The code below shows what I would **like** to do, but having a {{...}} inside another {{...}} results in a build error.

```
<table width="600px">
  {{#each model.tier1Competencies as |competency|}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{competency.domain}}</td>
        <td>{{competency.number}}</td>
        <td>{{current-course-helper competency.id}}</td>   // Works here
        <td>
            {{course-select
                content = model.tier1Team.tier1Courses
                optionValuePath = "content.id"
                optionLabelPath = "content.name"
                selected = {{current-course-helper competency.id}} // But I need it here
                prompt = "Available Courses..."
            }}
        </td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

Determining the value somewhere else first seems problematic because I need *competency.id* from the {{#each}} block to determine the value to pass to the component.

Is there some way to pass the result of the Handlebar Helper to the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
{{course-select
    content = model.tier1Team.tier1Courses
    optionValuePath = "content.id"
    optionLabelPath = "content.name"
    selected = (current-course-helper competency.id)
    prompt = "Available Courses..."
}}
```

It's called a nested helper, you can see examples of it for example in the [`concat` helper documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_concat). It can be used with any helper, and you can nest however many times you want!